# Observable from merged Observable.just and Subject emits nothing

Tags: kotlin, mvp, rx-java2

i have a chain of calls from a presenter to repository which returns an observable. This is the code:

Presenter:

```
private fun getCategories() =
        compositeDisposable.add(
            categoriesUseCase.getCategories()
                .timeout(TIMEOUT, TIMEOUT_UNIT)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(this::handleCategories, this::handleCategoriesTimeout)
        )
```

This is the usecase:

```
fun getCategories(): Observable<List<Category>> =
        repository.getCategories()
            .map { it.map { Category(it.id, it.text, it.icon) } }
```

This is the repo: //subject is BehaviorSubject.create()

```
    fun getcategories(): Observable<List<DiscoverabilityCategoryElement>> =
            Observable.just(storage.getCategories())
                .mergeWith { subject.flatMapIterable { it.categories }.publish() }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .doOnNext { Logger.d("Data", "next categories $it") }
                .filter { it.isPresent }
                .map { it.get() }
                .take(1)
                .doOnSubscribe { Logger.d("Data", "Subcribed categories") }


   fun saveApiResult(response: Response) {//This is being called after subscribe
        subject.onNext(response.categories)
        subject.onComplete()
    }
```

Method on storage will always return Optional.empty() (Meanwhile i'm developing)

My problem is, even seeing that subject.onNext is being called, that value never comes to the presenter, i've debug a bit and subject always returns false to hasObservables, maybe i'm losing my observer in some point?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call `publish()` on that line? It returns a `ConnectableObservable` which does nothing until `connect` is called. However, there is nothing on that line that would require sharing.

Try this:

```
fun getcategories(): Observable<List<DiscoverabilityCategoryElement>> =
        Observable.just(storage.getCategories())
            .mergeWith { subject.flatMapIterable { it.categories } } // <-------------
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnNext { Logger.d("Data", "next categories $it") }
            .filter { it.isPresent }
            .map { it.get() }
            .take(1)
            .doOnSubscribe { Logger.d("Data", "Subcribed categories") }
```

Comment: I've try with and without, and same result.

Comment: If you complete a `BehaviorSubject`, the value is gone. If the consumer is late, you won't see any value. Try with `ReplaySubject.createWithSize(1)` instead.

Comment: Let me try :) 2moretogo

Comment: No, same error, i've a breakpoint in directLineSubject.flatMapIterable { it.categories } and it is null at this point..

Comment: Problem was mergeWith{}, changed by mergeWith(Function) and now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was change

```
 .mergeWith { subject.flatMapIterable { it.categories }.publish() }
```

by

```
.mergeWith(subject.flatMap({ rootElement -> Observable.fromArray(element.categories.toOptional()) }))
```